# Finding maximum likelihood estimates

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, maximum-likelihood, geometric-probability

[Practise Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QcbV.jpg)

To find the ML, am I right in thinking you take the log of the function then differentiate it with respect to p?

I am a bit confused as to what to do with the data given and am not sure how to find f(0) and f(1). Can someone explain how to go about answering questions like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood is

$$L(\{ z_n \} \mid p)=\prod_{i=1}^n f_Z(z_i \mid p).$$

Given data $\{ z_n \}$, the MLE $\hat{p}$ is the maximizer of $L$ in the variable $p$.  It is usually easier to compute the maximizer of $\log(L)$, which is the same because $\log$ is strictly increasing. That last maximum can be computed by differentiation, so you're looking to solve the equation

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\frac{\partial f_Z}{\partial p}(z_i \mid p)}{f_Z(z_i \mid p)}=0.$$

Comment: I still don't understand. I have the two equations you gave to me already but I don't know how to use them or where to put the z data.

Comment: @MatheZlatan The data goes into $f_Z$ and its derivative, which depend on both $z_i$ and $p$. For example, $f_Z(1 \mid p)=p(1-p)^1$.

Comment: @MatheZlatan By the way, it may help to note that since $E[Z]=1/p-1$, the method of moments estimator $\hat{p}_m$ solves $\overline{Z}=1/\hat{p}_m-1$ or $\hat{p}_m=\frac{1}{1+\overline{Z}}$. In general the method of moments estimator and the MLE are not the same...but they tend to be at least close, and the method of moments estimator is often easier to compute. So this can give you some idea of what the MLE might be, to help guide your calculation.

Comment: I'm with you now! Just used this technique for a different distribution. Thanks for that!